# mat-select dropdown patchvalue not working?

Tags: javascript, angular

HTML:(Here I have dropdown to get selected value. I used value binding to get value.I have tried ngModel also but its not working. What is wrong in my code? can you help me?)

```
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select  placeholder="Team NO" formControlName="team" [(value)]="teamNO" required>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let list of teamList" [value]="list" >{{list}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
      teamList = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
      teamNO : any;
     ngOnInit(){
        this.operatorService.currentEditSchedule.subscribe((result: any) =>{
           if(!!result){
            console.log(result)
            this.teamNO = result.teamNo 
            }
         })
       }
```

Comment: Make sure team no you got from service is a string not a number.

Comment: Yes, youre right.. type is not matching thats why its not patching the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ngModel instead of value in mat-select:

```
     <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select  placeholder="Team NO" formControlName="team" [(ngModel)]="teamNO" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let list of teamList" [value]="list" >{{list}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bnmxdbvlyam?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-form-example.html)

In case you get a number from your backend, it can help to convert it to a string:

```
this.teamNO = result.teamNo + '';
```